# How can I assign a multi-line value to a bind variable?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, quotes

I'm declaring and initializing the variable like this:

```
var test CLOB
exec :test := q'<
many many lines
many many lines
>'
```

I suppose I didn't really expect this syntax of string-quoting to work outside of PL-SQL blocks, but if there a SQLPlus equivalent? In particular, is there a syntax that doesn't require mangling every line in between the quotes (putting an escape before every newline in the file)? I expect this SQLPlus script to be generated by a shell script, with the value of the clob just catted in from another file.

Comment: I find this post... But it won't work here on my end, I have oracle client 10.2.0.2.x. See if it fits to you: http://plsqlnotes.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/sqlplus-multi-line-quoted-text.html

Comment: Whatever you want to assign to the CLOB insert into a table and take it from there. If it is a file in the Oracle SQL Developer you have import functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute` actually creates and run a PLSQL anonymous block but it must fit in a single line. So you could instead explicitly write the the PLSQL block like this :

```
begin 
:test :=  q'<
many many lines
many many lines
>' ;
end; 
/
```

If it's convenient enough.

Comment: Yeh, I've been going that route now... but I can still only assign 4000 bytes at a time. So I've been breaking it up into 4000char chunks and appending. Not exactly elegant, but gets the job done.